# python not installed. An error occured during installation in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

> ```
> python is not installed. Installing...
> python not installed. An error occurred during installation:
>  Unable to resolve dependency 'python311 (= 3.11.2)'.
> python package files upgrade failed with exit code 1. Performing other installation steps.
> The upgrade of python was NOT successful.
> python not installed. An error occurred during installation:
>  Unable to resolve dependency 'python311 (= 3.11.2)'.
> visualstudio2019-workload-vctools v1.0.1 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
>
> Chocolatey upgraded 0/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
>  See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
>
> Failures
>  - python (exited 1) - python not installed. An error occurred during installation:
>  Unable to resolve dependency 'python311 (= 3.11.2)'.
> ```

I was expecting that this will install all the necessary items itself but an error occurred please help me

Comment: What is the command executed that results in this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing:

```
choco install -yf python311
```